# Making two php variables into one

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Ok so I have this code:

```
    foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
        if ((sizeof($obj['geo']['coordinates'])) > 1){
           $lat = $obj['geo']['coordinates'][0];
           $long = $obj['geo']           
           ['coordinates'][1];                              
         /* echo 'Coord: ' . $loc . '<br/>'; */
         /* echo 'Lat: ' . $lat . '<br/>';
         cho 'Long: ' . $long . '<br/> <br/>'; */
         }          
    }
   $loc = array($lat, $long);
```

The ideal is that both $lat and $long can be made into one element of an array, rather than two separate ones. I am using a Google Map API and need this to be one variable in order to plot it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$loc[] = $lat . $long;`

Comment: Using Javascript, you might want to have a look into `json_encode()`, those variables can be used in JS straight without any worries.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply concatenate the two variables together. But, knowing that you probably need to get these two pieces separately at some point, I would put a separator-character in the middle so that you can `explode()` the string out.

```
$loc[] = $lat . "|" . $long;
```

Later you can `explode` the location into two parts again:

```
$coordinates = explode("|", $loc[$x]);
$latitude    = $coordinates[0];
$longitude   = $coordinates[1];
```